# Webscraping Table with tr class data-key

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im a novice at python so bare with me. I am trying to web **scrape** a table from a dataset table on a real estate data website. I have previously run a similiar idea on on a property listing website in my region (United Arab Emirates) https://propertyfinder.ae Where I would run a script similar to this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

# Search Page with parameters included
pf = 'https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/search?c=1&ob=mr&page=1'

response =  get(pf, headers=headers)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

listings = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="card-list__item")
first = listings[0]

#Location Variable
location = first.find_all('p', class_='card__location')[0].text

#Size (sqft)
size = first.find_all('p', class_='card__property-amenity card__property-amenity--area')[0].text
```

and so on for other variables.

However, on this new data website, their html layout intrdouces a class type that I don't know how to use the find_all() function.

```
<table class="_1_lam64P">
        <thead>...</thead>
        <body>
                <tr class data-key="table-row_0">...</tr>
                <tr class data-key="table-row_1">...</tr>
                <tr class data-key="table-row_2">...</tr>
```

I tried doing the following,(even though I know it won't help me with indexing,) but it tells me the keyword can't be an expression.

```
listings = html_soup.find_all('tr', class_data-key_="table-row_0")
```

With this in mind, I want to be able to loop each table row and the subseqent pages by indexing the 'table-row_X' with 'X' progressing to each number. Similarly I would need to get the variables with the html5 format of

```
<tr class data-key="table-row_0">
        <td colspan="1" data-key="data-table-cell_price">..</td>
        <td colspan="1" data-key="data-table-cell_plot_area">..</td>
</tr>
```

How would I access the td attributes?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I used this as guide

https://towardsdatascience.com/looking-for-a-house-build-a-web-scraper-to-help-you-5ab25badc83e

Comment: I don't see any `table-row_0` on that site? or `_1_lam64p` class (have you provided a link to the new site?).  What details are you trying to get? Could you [edit] your question to show your first few rows of expected data

Comment: @MartinEvans the 'table-row_0' is on a website called https://datafinder.ae where you need a get past a pay wall to access the data. If you need specfic info I can try and provide.

Comment: Are you able to provide a larger snippet of the HTML? You can probably locate the table either with a class or a nearby `<div>`. You could then just read all `<tr>` ? Or are there some rows you want to skip over?

Comment: @MartinEvans Here is a link to the html file of the webpage https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZuNA_I8GHprJdZ8b_TuwE7DG3R8Xmoa/view?usp=sharing
, (sorry couldn't find a more effiicent way. Simply put, I want to collect all the valuesof all the rows of the table, and then repeat for as many pages as there are.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap.

Comment: @barny Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the values from that table, you can ignore the class for each row and just read all the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements in. The header can also be obtained via the `<th>` elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

with open('Record Data - Data Finder.html') as f_html:
    html = f_html.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
header = [th.text for th in soup.table.find_all('th')]
data = []

for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
    data.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
print(df)
```

Comment: How would I use `with open() as f_html` with a url instead of an html file? and since its behid a pay wall, is there a method to run the code thru my browser so that it can access the pages? And I guess the final step would be to make it cycle thru all the pages.

Comment: Update: The website runs like a web app and chanigng pages on the table does't chage the url, there is basically a next page div with an event tag on it
`<div class="_3rAkcwFt _10rWi6uP" data-key="paginator-item-next-page"><div class="_3yzH6IgI _1p6NuvAE"><span class="_34-GPJZM"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d=...></path></svg></span></div></div>` Which you can see in the html file

Comment: You don't need `with open()`, just use `requests.get(url)` as you have in your question

Comment: To access a next page really is a different (big) question, you need to make use of your browser's dev tools to watch what happens when the next button is pressed, this can then be used to form the correct request calls.

Comment: I think in that regard I will post a seperate question with all the information present, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select the answer as the accepted solution